# Error on deploying to artifactory using maven

Tags: maven, artifactory

I tried  to deploy a artifact to artifactory using maven. But I am getting an error 
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter

Detailed Logs are

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:657)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:875)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:798)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:281)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:998)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:994)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.555 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-30T06:23:49+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/360M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/mware/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/mware/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

So any help in this issue?

Comment: What are versions of Maven and Java are you using?

Comment: Actually we are trying to deploy a non Java artifact. The version of maven is 3.3.3 and Java jdk is 1.8.

Comment: How did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to update your version of the `maven-deploy-plugin`. There is a much newer version - `2.8.2`. There's also Maven `3.3.9` as well. This seems like a Plexus issue.

Comment: Actually I'm deploying to artifactory using Jenkins and the jenkins server is not in my control so updating might be an issue. Thanks

Comment: Try deploying from your own machine with the versions you have on your Jenkins. If it fails, try the ones I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but just in case someone ends up here trying to find help:
This error is caused by Maven resolving a dependency (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils) to an older version, probably 1.x where the class is simply not there.
This problem is caused most probably because on your (proxy) Nexus server maven-deploy-plugin has a generated pom file or even none, and it cannot resolve the dependencies correctly, so it falls back to plexus-utils:1.x
Solution: Download the original pom file and deploy it to your Nexus server (deploy:deploy-file). If your deploy plugin does not work anymore because of the corrupted dependency path, trick it by copying the pom file first in your local repository.